# How to serialize an object "datetime" property into a "date" elasticsearch type, not "text"

Tags: elasticsearch, serialization, foselasticabundle, jms-serializer

I am creating a website using Symfony 4.

Visitors will need to search through thousands of articles ordered by "dynamic_date". I use Elasticsearch 6.7, FOSElasticaBundle and JMS Serializer to index "Article" objects.

Serialization seems to somehow mislead ElasticSearch in terms of what the final indexed type should be and this prevents me from sorting search results.

How can I indicate it, either in configuration file or with annotations ?

I have tried to use the @Type annotation in order to force it into the correct type.

FOSElasticaBundle configuration file :

```
fos_elastica:

    serializer:
        serializer: jms_serializer

...

        articles:
            types:
                article:
                    serializer:
                        groups: [elastica]
```

Article Entity :

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

...

/**
 * @Serializer\Type("DateTimeImmutable")
 * @Serializer\Groups({"article_show", "list", "elastica"})
 * @var \DateTimeImmutable
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="change", field="state", value="published" )
 * @ORM\Column( name="dynamic_date", type="datetimetz_immutable", nullable=true)
*/
    protected $dynamic_date ;
```

ArticlesSearchRepository :

```
$query = new \Elastica\Query( $boolQuery ) ;

$query -> addSort
        (
            array
            (
                'dynamic_date' => array( 'order' =>  'desc' )
            )
        );
```

However, by checking  http://local:9200/articles , I can see that it always ends up being indexed as a "text" type instead of "date" type, which throws the following error :

> Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on > 
>   [dynamic_date] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the >inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory

whereas it works as expected when I set it manually (without using the serializer), like this :

```
        articles:
            types:
                article:
                    properties:
                        dynamic_date:
                            type: "date"
```

I would like to keep the benefits of using JMS Serializer though.